# how to create new row for Excel in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, apriori

There are 2 columns in an Excel file.

- In the first column, there are `LieferungNummer` values.
- In the second column there are `ProduktNummer` values.

A value in the `LieferungNummer` column matches more than one of its values in the `ProduktNummer` column.

What I want to do is to combine the values of a `LieferungNummer` in a new excel line.

I share two images:

- The first is the visual without processing
- The second is the visual that tells me what I want to do.

**Question:**

How can I do this with a function?